mu4e gmail setting (confuse about trash and all mail)

I should not sync my "all mail" to mu4e-refile-folder?
but my "all mail" somehow have more mail than all labels and inbox combined.

Why trashed mail in my trash folder not getting removed ?
I deleted the mail, it appear in the trash-folder, and in gmail it goes to trash?
And i deleted the mail files, the trashed mail get sync back to my trash-folder, but i don't see those mails in gmail trash, where did they sync from?


I am confused, what does "d" do in mu4e?
what should mu4e-refile-folder be?
what about mu4e-trash-folder ?

I don't understand your issue at all. But speaking about Gmail and trash, the section 8.4 of the Mu4e Info manual says "Some mailboxes behave differently however and they don't interpret the trash flag.  In cases like Gmail, the message must be moved to the
trash folder and the trash flag must not be used.". I hope taking this into account solves some of your problems.
